# Uncaught TypeError: App.Chart is not a constructor(…)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, constructor, turbolinks

I'm trying to upgrade my Rails app to use TurboLinks. In order for this to work all my javascripts need to be namespaced. I started using the following:

```
var CHART; CHART = {

    input_x: []
    input_y: []

    drawChart: function() {
       ...some code
    }

}
```

Then I can call this from coffee script as follows:

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->

  if $(".portal.show").length > 0

    # Load map
    CHART.drawChart()
```

The issue with this method is when a user leaves the portal/show page and then returns, the CHART object is not reset. With more complicated code, variables are not reset and can cause issues.

I'm trying to understand how to create a module. However, I encounter the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: App.Chart is not a constructor(…)
```

CoffeeScript:

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->

  if $(".portal.show").length > 0

    chart = new App.CHART()
    chart.drawChart()
```

Javascript:

```
App.CHART = (function() {

    function CHART() {
        this.input_x = [];
        this.input_y = [];
    }

    CHART.prototype.drawChart = function () {
        ...some code
    }

    return CHART;

})();
```

What is the best course of action?

I've tried using the guidance from this blog post, but I'm trying to keep my complicated javascript in javascript instead of converting to CoffeeScript:
http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/organizing-javascript-in-rails-application-with-turbolinks/

Comment: Well, `App.CHART` is indeed not a constructor. It's an object. This is because it's an IIFE, hence the function has _already been called_ and what you have there is the result. You need it to be a function instead, so you can call it with `new` - you can remove the IIFE for that.

Comment: Can you help me with the syntax. Somehow I don't get it.